# The tab where tools show up are all gray and I cant select the mode I want

Tags: color, selection-tools

I'm trying to color a model but the proper coloring tool is not showing up

[image: all grayed out]

Comment: punziletrix found the reason for the problem (not sure why the answer was deleted): *"it turns out I wrote something in the [search box](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/properties_editor.html#header)  and didnt notice. it went away when I deleted what I wrote"*

Comment: Maybe @DuarteFarrajotaRamos deleted the answer because he deemed it too poor in quality? Can't see any other reason since it seems to be the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Apologies, when I first read it I didn't realize it was an answer, looked like a comment about this site search feature, rather than Blender UI properties search feature. Could you elaborate a bit on your answer to improve it? Maybe provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wrote something in the *Properties Window* search box which highlights matching properties. Greyed out elements went away when I deleted what I wrote.